# given a infinite dimensional vector space over Complex field, can you find a list of linear independent list of any length?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following question with a different path,

Suppose there exists a linear map on V whose null space and range are both finite-dimensional, prove that V is finite-dimensional.

Now, instead of trying to build a basis from null space and rang T, I want to say that since V is infinite-dimensional, I can construct a list of linearity independent vectors of any length k>0. Specifically, $k>\dim $ range$ T =n$, now suppose $v_1,...,v_k$ are such linearity independent vectors, then $Tv_1,\dots, Tv_k$ are linearly independent in the range, but this is a contradiction since we can't have a length of independent list bigger than the dimension of the space.

Comment: FWIW, my advice would be to use [rank-nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: To your argument, why should the vectors $T v_{1}, \dots, T v_{k}$ be independent? The $v_{i}$ might all be in the kernel, for what we know.

Comment: Thank you, I see the argument doesn't quite work now with your explanation. But do you think the argument would work if we impose such T to be also injective?

Comment: To answer the question in your title. The following might be the theorem you are looking for. 

Theorem: A vector space $V$ is infinite dimensional if and only if there exists a sequence $v_1,v_1,. . .$ of vectors in $V$ such that for every $m\in Z^+$, we have that $v_1,. . .,v_m$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @Remu,if you assume $T$ is injective, then the null space is zero, and $T$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and the (finite-dimensional) range. But this is a trivial case of null-rank.

Comment: @Remu  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501541/prove-that-if-operatornameranget-and-operatornamenullt-are-finite-dime) is the link to the post I made. Seems like the proof is mostly correct. Just requires some minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem interesting and I think I found a proof.

Firstly, I have been told that this theorem only holds for vector spaces over the same field. So the question becomes the following.

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces defined over the same field $F$. Let $T : V\to W$ be a linear map. Suppose that range$T$ and null$T$ are finite dimensional. Prove that $V$ is finite dimensional.

Proof: Given that range$T$ is finite dimensional, there exists a basis of range$T$. Let $Tv_1,. . .,Tv_n$ be the basis of range$T$. Assuming that the function $T$ is not a partial function. We see that for every $v\in V$, $Tv\in$ range$T$. Because $Tv_1,. . .,Tv_n$ is a basis, there exists scalars $a_1,. . .,a_n$ such that $Tv=a_1Tv_1+. . .+a_nTv_n$. Subtracting $Tv$ from both sides and using the linearity of $T$ we get $T(a_1v_1+. . .+a_nv_n-v)=0$.

Given that null$T$ is finite dimensional. Let $w_1,. . .,w_m$ be a basis of null$T$. Then, $a_1v_a+. . .+a_nv_n-v=c_1w_1+. . .+c_mw_m$ $\implies$ $a_1v_a+. . .+a_nv_n-c_1w_1+. . .+c_mw_m=v$.

The list $v_1,. . .,v_n,w_1,. . .,w_m$ spans $V$ because $v$ was an arbitrary vector. Hence, $V$ is finite dimensional.

Note that this result is also consistent with the rank-nullity theorem. Note that you cannot use the rank nullity theorem to prove this as the rank nullity theorem already assumes that $V$ is finite dimensional.

I did post this proof as another question. Although I think the proof is correct. If someone finds a mistake, I will update you on it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following linear map from an infinite dimensional vector space to a finite dimensional vector space.

Define $T : (R, Q, +, \times) \to R^2$ by $T(x) = (x, x)$. We see that this function is a linear map. We also see that $range(T)$ and $null(T)$ are both finite dimensional. But $(R, Q, +, \times)$ is infinite dimensional.

Is something going wrong here? Because this disproves the statement.

I will ask this as a new question. Because I am confused about this now.

Comment: what is this vector space $(R,Q,+,\times)$ ? this is the first time I've seen this, can you elaborate a bit more? thx

Comment: @RupanX Yeah sure. This is just an alternative notation for a vector space. As you recall, a vector space consists of a set, a field and the operations of addition and scalar multiplication. In the above notation, the set is $R$, the set of real numbers. The field is $Q$ of rational numbers. The addition and multiplication symbol just denote the operations of addition and scalar multiplication. For example, we would write the vector space $R^2$ as $(R, R, + \times). This is the familiar Cartesian plane.

Comment: @RupanX I posted this question again, you might wanna keep an eye on that. Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500911/linear-maps-from-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space-to-a-finite-dimensional-ve?noredirect=1#comment9445751_4500911

Comment: Thanks, it's the real over the rational number, I didn't know they are infinite dimensional, I just learn this.

Comment: @RupanX Yeah they are. Also, I just realised I typed $R^2$ wrong in the previous comment. It should be $(R\times R, R, +, \times)$.