# Linear maps from an infinite dimensional vector space to a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I was just reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500774/given-a-infinite-dimensional-vector-space-over-complex-field-can-you-find-a-lis/4500904#4500904) asked to prove that if for a linear map $T$, we have that range$T$ and null$T$ is finite dimensional. Then we have that $V$ is finite dimensional.

But consider the following linear map from an infinite dimensional vector space to a finite dimensional vector space.

Define $T : (R, Q, +, \times) \to R^2$ by $T(x) = (x, x)$. We see that this function is a linear map. We also see that $range(T)$ and $null(T)$ are both finite dimensional. But $(R, Q, +, \times)$ is infinite dimensional.

I think I am doing something wrong here but Doesn't this seem to disprove the statement?

Comment: What field are your vector spaces defined over?

Comment: @JacobManaker The domain is defined over the rationals and the co-domain is defined over the reals.

Comment: First, you need to consider vector spaces over the same field. That's where the quoted theorem applies. So if you consider both over the rationals then ask yourself why is the range finite-dimensional? If you think it's one dimensional, then you need to think again.

Comment: @peek-a-boo oh okay. I’m gonna take some time to think about that. Thanks!

Comment: An even simpler example is $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(x) =x$, which demonstrates the same issue with the image.