# Prove that if $\operatorname{range}T$ and $\operatorname{null}T$ are finite dimensional, then $V$ is finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I posted this problem before but the proof was wrong. I think I have a correct proof now, hence I am posting it again.

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces defined over the same field $F$. Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map. Suppose that $\operatorname{range}T$ and $\operatorname{null}T$ are finite dimensional. Prove that $V$ is finite dimensional.

**Proof:** Given that $\operatorname{range}T$ is finite dimensional, there exists a basis of $\operatorname{range}T$. Let $Tv_1,\ldots ,Tv_n$ be basis basis of $\operatorname{range}T$. Assuming that the function $T$ is not a partial function. We see that for every $v\in V$, $Tv\in \operatorname{range}T$. Because $Tv_1,\ldots ,Tv_n$ is a basis, there exists scalars $a_1,\ldots ,a_n$ such that $Tv=a_1Tv_1+\cdots +a_nTv_n$. Subtracting $Tv$ from both sides and using the linearity of $T$ we get $T(a_1v_1+\cdots +a_nv_n-v)=0$.

Given that $\operatorname{null}T$ is finite dimensional. Let $w_1,\ldots ,w_m$ be a basis of $\operatorname{null}T$. Then, $a_1v_1+\cdots +a_nv_n-v=c_1w_1+\cdots +c_mw_m\implies a_1v_1+\cdots +a_nv_n-c_1w_1+\cdots +c_mw_m=v$.

The list $v_1,\ldots ,v_n,w_1,\ldots ,w_m$ spans $V$ because $v$ was an arbitrary vector.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: The proof looks correct. To make it clearer you could choose the basis beforehand, and after that choose a vector in $V$ and do the work you did. A weird line is "Assuming that the function $T$ is not a partial function". Why would it be? Imagine that in the middle of the proof I add "By the way, remember that $F$ is actually a field, not only a ring... ”

Comment: @jjagmath Noted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the proof is correct.

I think it would be better if you could explicitly use the definition of the range, that is for any vector in the range of $T$, $r\in \text{range}\;T$ there must be some $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=r$, and so if $r_i$ is a basis for $\text{range}\;T$ then $r_i=T(v_i)$ for some $v_i\in V$.

At the moment it looks like you pulled the $T(v_i)$ out of a hat or something, so people reading the proof might wonder how that is justified.